# Pattern matching against monadic result?

Tags: haskell, monads

I am learning Haskell and want to use "readHex", which according to Hoogle has type:

```
readHex :: Num a => ReadS a
```

How do you "extract" a result from such a function? What's the most common way, pattern match against the right constructor ie, [(a,"")] ??

LiftM and lifting in general seems to make some sense, but I'm lost when it comes to "unwinding" the monadic stack.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To answer the general question in general terms, the *only* way to extract values from a data constructor is pattern matching. Some data types come with functions that extract values for you, but those functions are themselves implemented with pattern matching, or call other functions that are, &c. Abstract data types like `Data.Map.Map` or `IO`, that want to hide their internal structure, still require pattern matching to work with; the difference is that they don't export their constructors from the module that defines them, so all you have to work with are other functions defined in the module and the operations they provide.

To answer the specific question, `ReadS` [is defined](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Text-ParserCombinators-ReadP.html#t%3aReadS) as such:

```
type ReadS a = String -> [(a, String)]
```

So it's just a type synonym. You don't need to extract anything from the `ReadS` itself, it's just a shorthand or alias. The actual type is `[(a, String)]`, which you can work with the same way you would anything else using lists, tuples, `String`s, and so on.

Furthermore, `ReadS` is not a `Monad`. It's a type synonym for something that isn't a `Monad` instance, and in fact can't be made into one directly (there's no way to write `[(a, String)]` in the form required for an instance declaration).

Answer (score 2):

There's nothing monadic here.  `ReadS` is simply a type alias ([link](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Prelude.html#t%3aReadS)).

If you execute:

```
> readHex "41A"
```

Then you will get a singleton list of a tuple:

```
[(1050,"")]
```

There are numerous ways to extract the value `1050`.  Some would use a `case` statement.  I would define an auxilary function using `listToMaybe`:

```
readHexToVal :: Num a => String -> Maybe a
readHexToVal = listToMaybe . map fst . readHex
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what's the advantage of `Maybe` over `[]`? The only function available for `Maybe` that has no real analogue for lists is `fromMaybe :: a -> Maybe a -> a`, and even then you could write yourself a `fromList x xs = head (xs ++ [x])` or so.

Comment: I like your idea of returning a Maybe. That way you get a Nothing instead of some function bombing out or a more complex "case".

Comment: @Daniel Wagner: I'd argue "more meaningful semantics". If you know a list will have at most one element, you can express that knowledge in the type system by converting it to a `Maybe`; then anything you do with the value later won't be forced to either handle cases that will never happen (more than one element) or use an inexhaustive pattern match (resulting in annoying errors at run time if you've made a mistake).

Comment: @Daniel There are rather few theoretical differences but it seems there are large differences in how people perceive things when you give them a `Maybe a` vs a `[a]` and tell them the list is of length 0 or 1.

Answer (score 2):

The type `ReadS a` is just a synonym for `String -> [(a, String)]`. This is a function that accepts one input string and gives a list of matches - the first element is the resulting value and the second is the string that matched. In your case, there is most likely only one match, so I suggest you to use it like this:

```
case readHex str of
  ((num,""):_) -> ...
  _            -> error ...
```

Comment: wouldn't it be _ -> error at the end to catch everything else?
ie, an invalid entry could be [(45, "arst")]

Comment: @overscore Only matches are in the list. If there is no match, the result is an empty list (the first case). A non-empty list has at least one element (the second case), so the pattern is exhaustive.

Comment: @FUZxxl: I think he meant that this code will silently accept partial matches: `readHex "FFy" = [(255,"y")]`.

Answer (score 0):

You can pull out the result using let:

```
let ((d, _):_) = readHex "123ab"
```