# Adding readHex to a Parsec parser

Tags: haskell, parsec

I'm going through Write Yourself a Scheme and am struck at the exercise 4 on [this page](http://jonathan.tang.name/files/scheme_in_48/tutorial/parser.html).

How do I go about this? I've got this far, but have no idea whatsoever where the `readHex` is supposed to go, must I `liftM` it ? Do you case match the parser ?

```
parseNumber = liftM (Number . read) $ choice [many1 digit, char '#' >> oneOf "hd" >>= a]
    where a f = case f of
        'h' -> many1 digit
```

Also, I don't suppose you can apply `<|>` on `Parser LispVal` functions, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I've got this far, but have no idea whatsoever where the readHex is supposed to go, must I liftM it ?

Yes, since `readHex` is most likely a pure function and `liftM` lifts it into the monadic context of `Parser`.

Since I don't quite understand what your local function `a` is good for, I'm leaving it for now and simply use the functions `parseDecimal` and `parseHex`. In that case, you could write `parseNumber` like so:

```
parseNumber :: Parser LispVal
parseNumber = liftM Number $ parseDecimal <|> parseHex
    where parseDecimal :: Parser Integer
          parseDecimal = liftM read $ many1 digit
          parseHex :: Parser Integer
          parseHex     = liftM readHex $ char '#' >> ... -- parse hex value
```

Of course you can omit the type signatures, I just added them for clarity.

> Also, I don't suppose you can apply <|> on Parser LispVal functions, right?

`<|>` works for every `Parser a`.

I recommend reading some material on parser combinators, i.e. the [Parsec User Guide](http://legacy.cs.uu.nl/daan/download/parsec/parsec.pdf).

Comment: It's not quite this straightforward, because of the type of `readHex :: Num a => String -> [(a, String)]`. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7181390/pattern-matching-against-monadic-result) for how to deal with that.

Comment: Thanks! Am closer to understanding now! Will accept your answer shortly if nothing else comes

Comment: Monadic parsing is very powerful and actually quite easy, once you worked it out. You might also want to have a look at Control.Applicative, which can lead to more consice parsers sometimes, and the current version of Parsec (because it seems that the tutorial is a bit outdated).

Answer (score 1):

I've changed the layout a bit, but here is the code example we are considering:

```
parseNumber = 
    liftM (Number . read) $ 
        choice [many1 digit, char '#' >> oneOf "hd" >>= a]
    where
    a f =
        case f of
            'h' -> many1 digit
```

I think you are trying to do too many things at the same time before knowing how things should go together. You somehow have to move a `readHex` into the `(Number . read)` part instead of `read`, depending on what type of digits were being read.

Here is a parser for hexadecimal numbers that doesn't use `liftM` or other fancy combinators:

```
parseHex :: Parser LispVal
parseHex = do
    char '#'
    char 'x'
    digits <- many1 hexDigit   -- hexDigit is defined by Parsec.
    return (Number (fst (readHex digits !! 0)))
```

The tricky part here is the extraction of the result of `readHex`.

You can combine parsers with

```
try parseHex <|> try parseOct <|> ... <|> parseDec
```

or get fancy with tuning and inlining and the many tools of Parsec. But I'd start with the basics.

Comment: Regarding the last code snippet - don't forget the 1st rule of of Parsec - "try to avoid `try`".